# Could not evaluate: Error evaluating 'unless' clause

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, puppet

It am trying to add 'replica' user to my postgres server though puppet so i can use it in my master-salve cluster.

when i do it manually ("CREATE ROLE replica ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '123';") it does work, but for some reason it does not work from the puppet.

From the puppet i get the error:

> Error: /Stage[main]/Role::Ofir_testing/Postgresql::Server::Role[replica]/Postgresql_psql[CREATE ROLE replica ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ****]: Could not evaluate: Error evaluating 'unless' clause, returned pid 2064 exit 1: ''
>
> Notice: /Stage[main]/Role::Ofir_testing/Postgresql::Server::Role[replica]/Postgresql_psql[ALTER ROLE "replica" NOSUPERUSER]: Dependency Postgresql_psql[CREATE ROLE replica ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ****] has failures: true

This is my pp file:

```
class { 'postgresql::globals':
  manage_package_repo => true,
  version  => $pg_version,
}

class { 'postgresql::server':
  ip_mask_deny_postgres_user => '0.0.0.0/32',
  ip_mask_allow_all_users    => '0.0.0.0/0',
  listen_addresses           => "localhost,${master_IP_address}",
}

postgresql::server::config_entry { 'archive_mode':
  value => 'on',
}
postgresql::server::config_entry { 'archive_command':
  value => "cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/${pg_version}/main/archive/%f",
}

postgresql::server::config_entry { 'wal_level':
  value => 'hot_standby',
}

postgresql::server::config_entry { 'synchronous_commit':
  value => 'local',
}

postgresql::server::config_entry { 'max_wal_senders':
  value => '2',
}

postgresql::server::config_entry { 'wal_keep_segments':
  value => '10',
}

file { "/var/lib/postgresql/${pg_version}/main/archive/":
  ensure  => 'directory',
  owner   => 'postgres',
  group   => 'postgres',
  mode    => '700',
  recurse =>  true,
}

postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { "Allow ${user} a replication connection from Localhost":
  description => 'Open up access from 127.0.0.1/32',
  type        => 'host',
  database    => 'replication',
  user        => 'replica',
  address     => '127.0.0.1/32',
  auth_method => 'md5',
  }

postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { "Allow ${user} replication connection from Master":
  description => 'Open up access from master',
  type        => 'host',
  database    => 'replication',
  user        => 'replica',
  address     => "${master_IP_address}/32",
  auth_method => 'md5',
}

postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { "Allow ${user} replication connection from Slave":
  description => 'Open up access from slave',
  type        => 'host',
  database    => 'replication',
  user        => 'replica',
  address     => "${slave_IP_address}/32",
  auth_method => 'md5',
}

postgresql::server::role { "${user}":
  password_hash      => postgresql_password("${user}", "${password}"),
  replication        => true,
  connection_limit   => 1,
}
```

The Error is in the 'role'.
i tried to add

```
  user                       => 'postgres',
  group                      => 'postgres',
```

to the 'postgresql::server' but it didn't help.

The only thing that did help is deleting the "manage_package_repo => true"
from 'postgresql::globals', but its doing problems when trying to install postgres version that is not the default.

Comment: Running the agent from the command line, with the `--test` option, should give you more details about what's failing, including the specific command that failed, and even what its exit code was.  That would be useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, the issue you was due to postgresql::server::role being applied before the server is created. 
this is the solution, thanks to Eimhin
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-8824